# Assign PHP variable to each row

Tags: php, mysql

The following mysql query is getting the last 4 records from the 'residential' table but I'm trying to assign a php variable ($postcode) to each row (the 3rd [3] column in particular) for use in on another page. The following doesn't seem to be split the rows out correctly to assign to each variable?

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("example.com","peter","abc123","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM residential ORDER BY My_id DESC LIMIT 4");

$postcodes = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
{
$postcodes[] = $row[3];
}

echo "location one " . $postcodes[0];
echo "<br>";
echo "location two " . $postcodes[1];
echo "<br>";
echo "location three " . $postcodes[2];

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Please clarify - you are just trying to hold onto the `postcode` column's value for later use?  Don't think of this as storing 4 variables. Instead store an array of postcodes.  `$postcodes[] = $row[3];`

Comment: You're looping through the results, you could always just put a counter your while loop and when it equals three, assign your variables.

Comment: Thank Michael...their for use in another php page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fetch` calls fetch a single ROW of data. You're just assigning column #3 of each row, over and over again.

You probably want:

```
$postcodes = array();
while ($row = ...) {
    $postcodes[] = $row[3];
}
var_dump($postcodes);
```

Comment: // comment: `list($postcode1, $postcode2, $postcode3, $postcode4) = $postcodes;`

Comment: I figured I was doing that Marc...how does the above fit in the original mysql code?

Comment: Exactly like it is, just fill in the `...` bits.